# Homotopy hypothesis and other geometric objects

Tags: category-theory

Does the homotopy hypothesis suggest that other geometric objects can be expressed as higher categories?

Thank you

Comment: What are "other geometric objects"?

Comment: What is the "homotopy hypothesis"?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 [Homotopy hypothesis](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+hypothesis).  Essentially, it says that spaces up to weak equivalence = $\infty$-groupoids.